# How to fix the adding to CSV file problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with 400+ rows and 2 columns containing movies and their genre.
I am trying to add at the end of my existing CSV file a new movie and a new genre.

I wrote this:

```
import csv

with open('/Users/Desktop/okok.csv','a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["newFilm", "newGenre"])
```

When I open the file after running this I see that `newFilm` was added to the last row, column `genre` and `newGenre`, in a new column in the same row.

I would like this:

```
Taken, Thriller
newFilm, newGenre
```

and I get this:

```
Taken, ThrillernewFilm, newGenre
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your original csv is correctly formatted? I just ran your code using a test csv file and it gave the exact results you want.

Comment: As you noticed the csv writer expects that a file ends with a linefeed, looks like your existing file didn't have one.

Comment: I just tried creating a new csv file and running this and i get the same problem, what did you do to try it out and make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

`okok.csv` wasn't a valid CSV file. Python's `csv` module assumes that each line in a CSV file is terminated with a newline. `okok.csv` wasn't, so the new row appended to the old row. Garbage in, garbage out.

The writer itself isn't in a position to rewind and check for validity. But you can write your own routine to fix this common bug if you have upstream writers of CSV who don't follow the rules. Call it before opening for your regular update.

```
def fix_csv_file_ending(filename):
    with open(filename, "ab+") as fileobj:
        fileobj.seek(-1, 2)
        if fileobj.read() != b"\n":
            fileobj.write(b"\r\n")

# test
lines = b'good\r\ngood\r\n\bad'
open('test.csv', 'wb').write(lines)
fix_csv_file_ending('test.csv')
want = lines + b'\r\n'
got = open('test.csv', 'rb').read()
assert want == got, 'first test'
fix_csv_file_ending('test.csv')
got = open('test.csv', 'rb').read()
assert want == got, 'second test'
print(got)
```